# Не запускается cmd.exe из программы на java

Tags: java

Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe") ;
        }
        catch (Exception e){System.out.println(e);
```

Если же попробовать запустить `calc.exe`, то все успешно, а вот командная строка - увы. Указание полного пути к `cmd` не помогло.

Comment: а зачем нужно делать дамп базы любому пользователю?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman , Не любому, программа имеет авторизацию, если входит администратор (не путь с администратором ОС), то у него появляется возможность сделать дамп БД, при этом на компьютере, куда вошел админ, может быть выполнен вход под учетной записью простого смертного. И по логике хотелось, чтобы при создании дампа открывалась cmd, вводился пароль админа (уже как учетной записи) и создавался дамп. Как-то так.

Comment: зачем вы делаете дамп базы?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman , чтобы потом пропустить его через программу шифрования, и на защите диплома сказать, как я умею защищать данные и что в наше время это неимоверно важно и мне надо ставить пятерку.

Comment: вам стоит исправить вопрос. так как в текущем виде на него сложно дать ответ.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, каким образом отредактировать? Я по прежнему хочу получить дамп из приложения на java.

Comment: а вопрос у вас про то, что внешняя программа не запускается как вам надо

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще вот такой вариант:

```
Process process =
        new ProcessBuilder("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe",
                "param1", "param2").start();
```